# Can anyone suggest some good tutorials for Lucene?

Tags: lucene

can anyone suggest me some good tutorials on Lucene. I was reading Lucene in Action, but it seems to be a old edition of current lucene. Most of the methods are deprecated.

Where to start? I am googling around a bit.

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true that there has been changes, but they're not as substantial as it might seem. The most radical change that I can think of is that the api for the IndexSearcher.search() method has changed, but it really isn't that difficult to adapt your code to the new usage.

In general, the old methods are still there but are marked as deprecated. This is a good thing, because the [reference manual](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/core/index.html) specifies what you should use instead.

Lucene in Action is a great book. Take a look at the second edition recommended by KenE if possible, but otherwise I think you'll get a long way using the first edition, the manual and some common sense. As I said, the changes are not as daunting as you could imagine.

Answer (score 6):

The second edition of Lucene in Action is available in electronic format [here](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/)

Answer (score 2):

[Lucid imagination](http://www.lucidimagination.com/) is a company offering support and consulting related to Lucene.
See [their Lucene tutorial](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Getting-Started-Lucene). They also have a [search engine](http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/) indexing lots of Lucene related material.

Answer (score 1):

I found this website useful
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-range-query.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick start tutorial can be found at [here.](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/index.html)